# Does iCalendar format allow overlapping dates?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am generating an [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) feed which will be consumed by other web services. I am wondering if iCalendar file format allows overlapping events, for example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//Fabricam Calendar//EN

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:EVENT1@fabricam.com
DTSTART:20151009T170000
DTEND:20151011T110000
SUMMARY:Event 1 -- Oct 09 to Oct 11
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:EVENT2@fabricam.com
DTSTART:20151010T170000
DTEND:20151020T110000
SUMMARY:Event 2 -- Oct 10 to Oct 20
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Note that the second event starts in the middle of first event. The feed validates perfectly. However when I import it in [Google calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/) then some/all events with overlapping dates are skipped.

I am wondering if this behavior described in specs. Or should I test all feed consumers to see how they behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely nothing that would say that you can't have overlapping events. It actually happens all the time !
On the other hand, you have all your DTSTART/DTEND in floating time (as opposed to UTC or local time with timezone). So the events may not end up where you think they are / Google may not like this type of events, especially given that they span multiple days.